# How to log queries to stdout on MySQL?

Tags: mysql

`MySQL 5.6.26`

Trying to log queries to stdout doesn't work below,

```
$ mysqld --general_log=1 --general_log_file=/dev/stdout
```

Comment: Why do you want to send your life to stdout?

Comment: This is not a great idea. Why do you want to do this? There are probably better ways to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: Maybe for use in Docker, and analysing slow queries with something like elasticsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, not directly. [The query logs only go to files, tables or nowhere](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/log-destinations.html). They don't seem to go to `/dev/stdout` nor honor [the `-` convention](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename). Don't worry, there's a much better way.

If all you want to do is see the query log as it happens, you can stream the log file using various Unix utilities. `tail -f` is one option.

```
tail -f /path/to/query.log
```

I prefer opening the log with `less` and using the `F` command to keep reading as the file is added to. It's like `tail -f` but you can also scroll around and search the file.

```
$ less /path/to/query.log
~
~
/opt/local/lib/mysql56/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.6.27-log (Source distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 0  Unix socket: (null)
Time                 Id Command    Argument
151004 16:10:51     1 Connect   schwern@localhost as  on 
                    1 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
151004 16:10:53     1 Query     select 1
151004 16:10:54     1 Quit      
Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)
```

Comment: `MySQL` seems more restrictive in view of security, while `Postgres` puts more trust on the user so allows you to send log to output.

Comment: @sof When it comes to MySQL, my inclination is to attribute accident rather than design. One needs deliberate code to write to a filehandle, and somebody probably thought it would be a good idea to avoid writing to special files (like `/dev/stdout`) as a general practice. And as much as it is my inclination to say showing queries on STDOUT is a security problem, it's probably *more* secure than putting them into a file; STDOUT has the advantage of being ephemeral.

Answer (score 9):

I am very surprised at how difficult it is to do this in MySQL vs. PostgreSQL.

Following below is the config that allowed me to send all MySQL logs to the Docker container's stdout.

Contents of `docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
---
version: "3.9"
services:
  your_db:
    image: mysql:5.7-debian
    command:
      - /usr/local/bin/mysqld.sh
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "$your_db"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "$your_pass"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "$root_pass"
      MYSQL_USER: "$your_user"
    volumes:
      - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf:ro
      - ./mysqld.sh:/usr/local/bin/mysqld.sh:ro
    networks:
      - your_net
```

Contents of `my.cnf`:

```cnf
[mysqld]
# Log General
general_log = 1
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql_general.log

# Log Error
log_error = /var/log/mysql_error.log

# Log Slow
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql_slow_query.log
long_query_time = 0  # 0 has the effect of logging all queries
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1
```

Contents of `mysqld.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

##
# This script exists to work-around the fact that
# mysql does not support logging to stdout
#
# This will tail the file logs configured in ./my.cnf
##

LOG_PATHS=(
  '/var/log/mysql_general.log'
  '/var/log/mysql_error.log'
  '/var/log/mysql_slow_query.log'
)
for LOG_PATH in "${LOG_PATHS[@]}"; do
  # https://serverfault.com/a/599209
  ( umask 0 && truncate -s0 "$LOG_PATH" )
  tail --pid $$ -n0 -F "$LOG_PATH" &
done

docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld
```